# How to init 2 DynamicSupervisors under one Supervisor

Tags: elixir

the problem is that when in Supervisor you try this:

```
children = [
  {
    DynamicSupervisor,
    name: SomeName,
    strategy: :one_for_one
  },
  {
    DynamicSupervisor,
    name: AnotherName,
    strategy: :one_for_one
  }
]
```

You end up receiving this:

> ** (Mix) Could not start application eap:
>
> PocAbilityProvider.start(:normal, []) returned an error: bad child
>   specification, more than one child specification has the id:
>   DynamicSupervisor. If using maps as child specifications, make sure
>   the :id keys are unique. If using a module or {module, arg} as child,
>   use Supervisor.child_spec/2 to change the :id, for example:
>
> children = [   Supervisor.child_spec({MyWorker, arg}, id:
>   :my_worker_1),   Supervisor.child_spec({MyWorker, arg}, id:
>   :my_worker_2) ]

I tried to pull off something like

## OPTION1

```
children = [
  {
    DynamicSupervisor,
    name: SomeName,
    strategy: :one_for_one,
    id: :unique_id
  },
  {
    DynamicSupervisor,
    name: AnotherName,
    strategy: :one_for_one,
    id: :even_more_unique_id
  }
]
```

## OPTION2

```
children = [
  {
    DynamicSupervisor,
    [
      [
        name: SomeName,
        strategy: :one_for_one
      ],
      id: :unique_id
    ]
  },
  {
    DynamicSupervisor,
    [
      [
        name: AnotherName,
        strategy: :one_for_one
      ],
      id: :even_more_unique_id
    ]
  }
]
```

But it still returns same error. Is it possible to start two DynamicSupervisors under one supervisor?

Answer (score 2):

[`DynamicSupervisor.child_spec/1`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.4/lib/elixir/lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex#L182) implicitly defines `:id` as the module name, `DynamicSupervisor`. To overcome this, one might either use [module-based supervisors](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html#module-module-based-supervisors) for both, with different modules (it won’t be DRY if the behaviour should be exactly same,) or use am explicit [`Supervisor.child_spec/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#child_spec/2) as:

```
children = [
  Supervisor.child_spec(
    {DynamicSupervisor, []},
    id: :id1, name: :name1, strategy: :one_for_one),
  Supervisor.child_spec(
    {DynamicSupervisor, []},
    id: :id2, name: :name2, strategy: :one_for_one)
]
```

This wrapper would overwrite the default `id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
children = [
  Supervisor.child_spec(
    {DynamicSupervisor, name: SomeName, strategy: :one_for_one}, 
     id: :dyn_sup_1), 
  Supervisor.child_spec(
    {DynamicSupervisor, name: AnotherName, strategy: :one_for_one}, 
     id: : dyn_sup_2)]
```

This is it the correct order to start two or more DynamicSupervisors